# IOS double tap trigger 2 segues

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, saslidemenu

i'm currently working on a ios App which is based on https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu (side menu classes) and a storyboard.

On my right menu I've connected a button with a custom segue (SASlideMenuPushSegue).
This is working fine in a normal use but if i'm tapping fast enough on the button, i can manage to push more view.

For example, if i m double tapping on the button 2 views will be pushed.
I have no idea where it comes from. Here is the segue code :

```
-(void) perform{

SASlideMenuRightMenuViewController* source = self.sourceViewController;
SASlideMenuRootViewController* root = source.rootController;
SASlideMenuNavigationController* destination = self.destinationViewController;

[root pushRightNavigationController:destination];
}
```

Any idea of the source of this bug ? 
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried restricting the tap until the segue is pushed?

Comment: How can i do that ? None of my code is called on the tap, the segue is directly connected in the storyboard.

Comment: Here is a similar post :

  [link to post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156441/ios-storyboard-segue)

Comment: That is just a post to how to trigger a segue, how can it prevent my bug from happening ? I will try it anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: that is usefull and you could intercept when the user presses the button.

Comment: Trigger the segue programatically does not change anything, i can set with boolean to prevent it but i think there is a cleaner way to prevent this. System segue does not seem to have this problem.

Comment: You wrote it yourself, you're using a custom control.

Comment: Only the segue is custom, i tought there were a problem maybe in this part of the code and not in my ViewController. This custom segue will be triggered in other view and i dont want to have to handle the problem in all the views !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `BOOL isPressed` inside and check if the button was pressed before in that particular class.

```
-(void) perform
{
     if(!isPressed)
     {
      SASlideMenuRightMenuViewController* source = self.sourceViewController;
      SASlideMenuRootViewController* root = source.rootController;
      SASlideMenuNavigationController* destination = self.destinationViewController;

      [root pushRightNavigationController:destination];
      isPressed = YES;
     }
}
```

and just reset `isPressed`. I encountered the same thing with segue when i presented a `popovercontroller` it was pressenting each time i was pressing the button one over another,so i think we need to handle this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, when do you reset the boolean to NO then ? I was thinking to a similar solution but i can not manage to find the correct place to reset the boolean !

Comment: you can reset in in viewDidDissapear or you can call a NSNotification from the destination controller to reset that Bool when the view appears

Comment: I dont understand, i have to keep an instance of the segue in my viewController ?

Comment: That is what i understood from you, i think the code will be enough, go ahead and try it out.

Comment: I'm goona try your way, but i have not any instance, the segue is directly triggered from the event button in storyboard. I ll comment to let you know if it worked.

Comment: You need to set the the segue as custom so the perform method can be overriten to the code above

Comment: I did this but having a instance of the segue seem to make me loose all interest of storyboard : I instance it with :     initWithIdentifier:source:destination:                                  Is there an other way ?

Comment: Then link it directly from the storyboard and listen for taps in this method : -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

Comment: Thank you for you answer, that seem to work but the viewDid(Will)Disapear methods are not called, i've tried to reset the booean at the end of the if in the segue and this is not working too, i m trying to find a proper place to reset it.

Comment: is your viewcontroller alive all the time? if it isn't then the reset won't be needed.

Comment: Yes the view controller is alive all the time.

Comment: as an fix you could create a reset method and perform a selector with delay after 1.0s to reset the bool ,not sure how much it helps but if you don't want it like this you could add an notification center observer to the view attached to the reset method and post a notification when it reaches the viewDidLoad of the second viewcontroller.

Comment: I think this is not a clean way is there a logical way to put it in the right place in code ?

Comment: i don't know how your project looks , it should call the viewWillDissapear and viewDidDissapear methods and it isn't , you can try placing the reset into the viewWillAppear method, or else ,send me a demo of what you are doing so i can help you.

Comment: I think this problem is a problem with the SASlideMenu class becaus my button is on the side menu and i think the class is just adding my view on top on the menu, the view never really "dissapear" to me

Comment: so can't you detect when the view overlaps?

Comment: I'm currently tring to find a way to do it, but the class does not seem to have callbacks. I was thinking to try to wait the end of the performsegue method if it is possible ?

Comment: you need to wait , so if you do that inside the same method it will cancel itself.

Comment: Yeah SASLide is missing so much calls like the viewdidAppears on first show on the view.